# Yii2 gii генерировал crud с контроллером ProductController, но путь /product/index выводит ошибку 404?

Tags: yii2

После gii генерации crud,  получил контроллер `ProductController`  со всеми  методамы,

метод  `actionIndex`  существует,  но путь  `/product/index` и просто `/product/` выводят 404 ошибку,

Что делать ?

Если создаю конструктор в  классе  `ProductController` он срабатывает но код до метода `actionIndex` не доходит.

Answer (score 0):

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [],
    ],
```

Если urlManager включен, то покажи нам его